# How do I get Logback to work nicely with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, logback

How do I get my logging framework (currently Logback) to play nicely with Eclipse?  In particular, it would be nice to click on a log statement and be taken to the line where it was produced.

I'm aware of the [Logback Eclipse Plugin](http://logback.qos.ch/consolePlugin.html) however apparently it is outdated, and only works with an old version of Logback.

Is there some other logging framework that works better with Eclipse?  I assume there must be a nice way to do this.

Comment: What are your logback lines looking like?

Comment: I'm using this pattern: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n

Comment: Logback-beagle was released just a few months ago. Please give it a try.

Comment: @Ceki: Sadly, logback-beagle doesn't work with Kepler. For a nice way to format log output in your console and "linkify" the line in the code, try Grep Console (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23358350/983430) to another question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `%caller`to the pattern, then the functionality of the Console of Eclipse can handle your problem...

Comment: For some reason if i use %caller I get a /n in the out put.  This is what Im' using: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} [%caller] %msg%n"  The ] and the text of the message appear on their own line.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a solution to this issue. I have never seen this.

Answer (score 17):

I use this pattern:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level (%file:%line\) - %message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

The (%file:%line) part is by default clickable in the Eclipse console.

Comment: nicer than the caller which is too verbose

Comment: Agree with @StijnGeukens - the caller output is hard to read, and `(%file:%line\)` does the job nicely (note the backslash, as parentheses have special meaning in logback which wasn't the case for log4j). +1, this is the better answer.