# Logback, Eclipse, and Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm having a problem with getting eclipse to recognize links in logging output.  I have a standard maven project with classes in src/main folder and classes in a src/test folder.  If I use the logging strategy outlined here:

[How do I get Logback to work nicely with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131741/how-do-i-get-logback-to-work-nicely-with-eclipse)

The links work for java files in src/main but do NOT work for files in src/test.  How do I get the links for files in src/test to work?

This is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- JUNIT https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUNIT-TOOLBOX https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.junit-toolbox/junit-toolbox -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.junit-toolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-toolbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SLF4J LOGBACK CLASSIC https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HTTPCLIENT https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ORG.JSON https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This is my logback.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level (%file:%line\) - %message%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This is the version of Eclipse I'm using:

```
Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.9.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201804120921
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a)

Copyright (c) 2007 - 2018 Pivotal Software, Inc.
All rights reserved. Visit http://spring.io/tools/sts
```

Comment: For me your setup is working for "normal" and test classes. Do you have a second logging config in src/test/resources? Do you see the log message but is is just not clickable?

Comment: I see the log message, it is just not clickable.

Comment: did you check if there is a logback.xml or logback-test.xml in the test resources?